# Look for matching values in 2 separate JSON files

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the 2 following JSON files which are stored locally in my project folder.

File 1

```
{"_links":{"self":[{"href":"http://val1"},{"href":"http://val2"},{"href":"http://val3"},{"href":"http://val4"},{"href":"http://val5"}]}}
```

File 2

```
{"_embedded":{"accountList":[{"accountNumber":"1234","link":{"href":"http://val3/newAccount"}}]}}
```

I am trying to write a function which looks for matching values(specifically the 'link' values) in the 2 files. The second file however has additional url parameters.

**So in summary I want to match "href":"http://val3" in file 1 with "href":"http://val3/newAccount"in file 2.**

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: well for now if I find a match then just a console.log to say ("match found") else ("no matches found")

Comment: Do you want to check whether the account link is present in links list?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have kept the mapping as an object and the values would be the matching hrefs from link2. Since there could be multiple values with the same prefix, I have set it as an array. Feel free to remove the `.push` and replace with `=` if you want only the last matching value

```js
let file1 = {"_links":{"self":[{"href":"http://val1"},{"href":"http://val2"},{"href":"http://val3"},{"href":"http://val4"},{"href":"http://val5"}]}}

let file2 = 
{"_embedded":{"accountList":[{"accountNumber":"1234","link":{"href":"http://val3/newAccount"}}]}}

let href1 = file1._links.self.map(i => i.href);
let href2 = file2._embedded.accountList.map(i=> i.link.href);

let mapping = href2.reduce((acc,ref) => {
   let prefix = href1.find(_ref => ref.startsWith(_ref));
   if(prefix){
     if(!acc[prefix]) acc[prefix] = [];
     acc[prefix].push(ref);
   }
   return acc;
},{});

console.log(mapping);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `indexOf` function to tell if a *string* contains a certain *substring*. That case will reflect a match. It looks something like this

```js
const objOne = {"_links":{"self":[{"href":"http://val1"},{"href":"http://val2"},{"href":"http://val3"},{"href":"http://val4"},{"href":"http://val5"}]}};
const objTwo = {"_embedded":{"accountList":[{"accountNumber":"1234","link":{"href":"http://val3/newAccount"}}]}};

objTwo._embedded.accountList.forEach(longLink => {
  objOne._links.self.map(l => l.href).forEach(shortLink => {
    if (longLink.link.href.indexOf(shortLink) != -1)
      console.log('Found match!', longLink);
  });
});
```